# linear programming python gurobi

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, gurobi

I am working on a single machine scheduling problem where the goal is to minimize weighted delay. I have created a model using Python/Gurobi, but I'm experiencing issues with the objective function as it is producing suboptimal results. Interestingly, when I transfer the model to OpenSolver in Excel, I get better results.

```
import gurobipy as gp


N = 15 # number of jobs

# w: weights of jobs
w = [1, 10, 9, 10, 10, 4, 3, 2, 10, 3, 7, 3, 1, 3, 10]

# p: process time of jobs
p = [26, 24, 79, 46, 32, 35, 73, 74, 14, 67, 86, 46, 78, 40, 29]

# d: due dates of jobs
d = [397, 405, 433, 443, 424, 372, 392, 461, 432, 409, 400, 385, 464, 411, 427]

# Create a new model
m = gp.Model()
x = {}
goal = m.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.CONTINUOUS)

#T : Tardiness

#C : Completion time

T = m.addVars(N,lb=0)
C = m.addVars(N)
K = m.addVars(N)
weight = {j: w[j] for j in range(N)}

#x[i,j]:The variable xij is a variable that takes a value of 1 when Job i is assigned to Sequence j, and takes a value of 0 in all other cases.

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        x[i,j] = m.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.BINARY)
        
# Set objective function: "The sequencing of jobs in a way that minimizes the total weighted delay."

m.setObjective((goal), gp.GRB.MINIMIZE)

# Add constraints

# Constraint1: Each job must be assigned to a sequence.

for i in range(N):
    m.addConstr(gp.quicksum(x[i,j] for j in range(N)) == 1)

#Constraint2: Each sequence must be assigned a job.

for j in range(N):
    m.addConstr(gp.quicksum(x[i,j] for i in range(N)) == 1)
    
    
#Constraint3: If Job i is assigned to Sequence j, then the processing time of Job i is assigned to Sequence j.

for j in range(N):
    m.addConstr(gp.quicksum(p[i]*x[i,j] for i in range(N)) == K[j])
    
#Constraint4: If Job i is assigned to Sequence j, then the weight of Job i is assigned to Sequence j.

for j in range(N):
   m.addConstr(gp.quicksum(w[i]*x[i,j] for i in range(N)) == weight[j])
   

#Constraint 5: The completion time of Sequence j is the sum of the completion time of the previous sequence and the processing time of the job assigned to Sequence j.
  
C[0].lb = 0
for j in range(1, N):
    m.addConstr(C[j-1] + K[j] == C[j])

#Constraint 6: If the completion time is greater than the due date, then there is a tardiness.
for j in range(N):
    m.addConstr(T[j] >= C[j] - gp.quicksum(x[i,j]*d[i] for i in range(N)))

#goal: The sequencing of jobs in a way that minimizes the total weighted tardiness.
m.addConstr(gp.quicksum(T[j]*weight[j] for j in range (N)) <= goal)

m.addConstr(C[0] == K[0])
m.addConstr(T[0] >= C[0] - d[0])
# Solve the problem
m.optimize()

# Print solution
print('Optimal objective value: %g' % m.objVal)
print('Solution:')
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if x[i,j].X > 0.5:
            print('x[%d,%d] = %d' % (i,j,x[i,j].X))
```

I would appreciate any assistance in improving the objective function in my Python/Gurobi model to match the results obtained from OpenSolver in Excel.

Comment: This would be a lot easier to troubleshoot if you added some code comments on ALL of your variables, and possibly some of the constraints that aren't obvious to help readability.  What does `x[i,j]` signify?  `T`?  `d`? ...

Comment: I agree with @AirSquid. I never understood this fetish for 1-character names for variables, arrays, constraints etc. Why don't people use names like StartTime, Duration, CapacityUsed and similar. Makes it easier to understand what is meant and hence easier to check the model. I have found many modellng mistakes in peoples' models just through renaming with sensible names; then silly mistakes can become obvious.

Comment: try using m.update() just before optimize line & check if it improves the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I added the necessary explanations to the code as per your suggestions. I think I'm making a mistake in the constraint for assigning weights to the sequences of jobs. I haven't been able to solve it yet.

Comment: Why does Constraint 4 not have a for loop?

Comment: Yes, you are right, there should be a for loop and I added it.

Answer (score 0):

You should write out the LP file for both approaches to see whether they differ at some point. This is generally recommended to double-check your formulation and see whether it actually matches the mathematical model.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a running version of gp, so this isn't tested, but....

You appear to be treating `weight` as a model variable in Constraint 4, and it is NOT a model variable, so I think you have some undefined behavior there and surprisingly not an error?

So I think you can either:

(a) make it a model variable

(b) instead of capturing tardiness, `T` in constraint 6, you could just make `T` the "weighted tardiness" and include the `w` parameter there because you have the known pairing of job to sequence there...  something like:

```
#Constraint 6: If the completion time is greater than the due date, then there is a WEIGHTED tardiness.
for j in range(N):
    m.addConstr(T[j] >= (C[j] - gp.quicksum(x[i,j]*d[i] for i in range(N))*w[i]) )
```

And then, of course, delete constraint 4 completely; remove `weight` from the problem, `w[i]` is sufficient; and remove the `weight` variable in the goal statement